# Why does this array not reverse in the correct order?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array that is outputting the following:

`[L,W,L,W,L,L,W,W]`

This is the correct values but I would like it reversed so it reads

`[W,W,L,L,W,L,W,L]`

This is my code:

```
for value in forms {

    if let arr = [value] as? [[String:Any]] {

        self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }

        for form in self.leagueForm {
            self.formGuide.append(form.player_result!)
            self.formGuide = self.formGuide.reversed()

        }                       
    }
}
print ("update" ,self.formGuide)
```

Without the line `self.formGuide = self.formGuide.reversed()` it has the correct values but wrong order, with this line it changes the output completely to:

`[W,L,W,W,L,L,L,W]`

This is totally incorrect???

UPDATE: info as requested:

```
[KeepScore.ShowCommunityViewController.Form(player_result: Optional("L"), player_name: Optional("Dicky"), result_date: Optional("2017-02-23"), result_id: Optional("93"))]
[KeepScore.ShowCommunityViewController.Form(player_result: Optional("W"), player_name: Optional("Dicky"), result_date: Optional("2017-02-23"), result_id: Optional("90"))]
[KeepScore.ShowCommunityViewController.Form(player_result: Optional("L"), player_name: Optional("Dicky"), result_date: Optional("2017-02-23"), result_id: Optional("89"))]
[KeepScore.ShowCommunityViewController.Form(player_result: Optional("W"), player_name: Optional("Dicky"), result_date: Optional("2017-02-23"), result_id: Optional("88"))]
[KeepScore.ShowCommunityViewController.Form(player_result: Optional("L"), player_name: Optional("Dicky"), result_date: Optional("2017-02-22"), result_id: Optional("57"))]
[KeepScore.ShowCommunityViewController.Form(player_result: Optional("L"), player_name: Optional("Dicky"), result_date: Optional("2017-02-22"), result_id: Optional("56"))]
[KeepScore.ShowCommunityViewController.Form(player_result: Optional("W"), player_name: Optional("Dicky"), result_date: Optional("2017-02-22"), result_id: Optional("55"))]
[KeepScore.ShowCommunityViewController.Form(player_result: Optional("W"), player_name: Optional("Dicky"), result_date: Optional("2017-02-22"), result_id: Optional("54"))]`
```

Updated code:

```
if let forms = json?["playerForm"] as? [[String: Any]] {

    print (forms)

    for value in forms {

        if let arr = [value] as? [[String:Any]] {

            self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }
            self.formGuide = self.leagueForm.flatMap { $0.player_result }.reversed()

        }
    }
    print ("update" ,self.formGuide)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to reverse you array each time it enter the for loop? It's unclear what you want to do.

Comment: I want my current output `[L,W,L,W,L,L,W,W]` to be reversed, so it is `[W,W,L,L,W,L,W,L]`

Comment: I thought .reversed would do it but it doesnt

Comment: why use all those loops and not `.reversed()` only ?

Comment: It's part of a bigger dictionary (that bits more complicated) currently it is outputting the correct values, I just want them in reverse order

Comment: Imagine First iteration: A, you do reverse. Seconde Iteration A,B, you do reverse => B,A, Third Iteration B,A,C, you do revers C,A,B ? No ?

Comment: @RDowns Can you please add the console log for `let array = self.formGuide.map {$0.player_result!}; print(array)`

Comment: and if you move the `.reversed()` right before the `print` ? The thing here is that you are reversing, adding reversing again, adding reversing again again etc...

Comment: I've updated with what i get if i `print (self.leagueForm)` after flatMap

Comment: just extract the array out of the dict, use `.reversed` on it, then add it back to the dict, it will override the current one isnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are making array reversed inside the for loop where you are adding object in array that is the reason you are getting this issue.

To solve this simply put line `reversedArray = reversedArray.reversed()` after the `for loop` or avoid the `for loop` and use `flatMap` same way you have used to create Array of object from Array of Dictionary.

```
self.formGuide = self.leagueForm.flatMap { $0.player_result }.reversed()
```

**Edit:** You are adding `for loop` inside the if let and there is no necessary of it.

```
if let forms = json?["playerForm"] as? [[String: Any]] {

    self.leagueForm = forms.flatMap { Form($0) }
    self.formGuide = self.leagueForm.flatMap { $0.player_result }.reversed()
}
```

Comment: I have taken out every thing after ` if let arr = [value] as? [[String:Any]] {` and added in that line only but it doesn't output anything.  It doesn't error but I get an output of "update []"

Comment: Ok I've done that but it I am only getting the first value in the array - update["W"] - i will update the question with my code

Comment: Thanks Nirav, when I tried the above I ended up with the array `[W,L,W,W,L,L,L,W]` again.  But thank you, it was simply just a case of reversing the formGuide in the end!

Comment: @RDowns Because you are trying to use for loop I have not told you to do that way. I have told you to use flatMap also there is unnecessary for loop no need of it, Simply check my solution one more time. Check once the **Edited** tag code.

Comment: Thank you Nirav for the full explanation of what I was doing wrong - that has worked and simplified my code.  It has also speeded up the drawing of the array represented on my app :)

Comment: @RDowns Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need

```
self.formGuide = forms.reversed()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply just call

```
self.formGuide.reverse()
```

where you want to access the array in reversed order, for example in your further code execution or to store it. Just dont call it in the loop where you adding stuff to the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe keep your first code example and just put the `self.formGuide = self.formGuide.reversed()` after the `for loop`

```
for value in forms {
    if let arr = [value] as? [[String:Any]] {
        self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }

        for form in self.leagueForm {
            self.formGuide.append(form.player_result!)
        }
    }
}

self.formGuide = self.formGuide.reversed()
print ("update" ,self.formGuide)
```